# iOS 10: SCNLight of type Omni ignoring attenuation values?

Tags: ios, scenekit, ios10

I have a simple `SceneKit` scene with only two light sources (ambient and omni) and one model. I have noticed that my scene appears totally dark when running on `iOS 10` (even before I recompiled my app with the `iOS 10` SDK). After investigating I realized that my ambient light was the only one affecting my model.

The only way to make my omni light affect my model was to bring it really close to it, or to increase its intensity (using the new `setIntensity:` selector) by a factor of `5000000`.

Changing the values of `attenuationStartDistance`, `attenuationEndDistance`, and `attenuationFalloffExponent` didn't change the result, which is really odd, considering that if I use `0.0` for both distances then I shouldn't expect any attenuation, and yet it happened (hence the need to use this huge intensity value).

This result doesn't change even if I add the `SCNDisableLinearSpaceRendering` key to my `Info.plist` or the `SCNDisableWideGamut` key.

Am I missing some new parameter or is it an `iOS 10` bug?

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to change the result after changing the values of `attenuationStartDistance`, `attenuationEndDistance`, and `attenuationFalloffExponent`, but only when using that huge `intensity` value. `iOS 10` is definitely not ignoring these parameters.

However, it seems that `iOS 10` is applying yet another attenuation on top the previous one. It is also attenuating the `intensity` value automatically, regardless of those parameters. Perhaps it's treating this new `intensity` parameter as if in a physically based renderer, even when it's not?

So, if you have a distant omni light source, it seems that you'll still need a big `intensity` for it to be bright enough from a distance, even if you disable the attenuation.

**EDIT**

`iOS 10` is indeed using a physically based lighting model as the new default! After loading a model, `iOS 9` will have `SCNLightingModelBlinn` for the `lightingModelName` property of the material whereas `iOS 10` will have `SCNLightingModelPhysicallyBased`. You can achieve `iOS 9` behavior by changing the value of that property after loading your model.

```
for(SCNMaterial * mt in model.geometry.materials)
    mt.lightingModelName = SCNLightingModelBlinn;
```